# What happens to a SemaphoreSlim when you dereference it?

Tags: .net-core, httpclient, semaphore

I'm running into a problem sending massive requests to a .NET Core web service.  I'm using a SemaphoreSlim to limit the number of simultaneous requests.  When I get a 10061 error (the web service has refused the connection), I want to dial back the number of simultaneous requests.  My idea at the moment is to de-reference the SemaphoreSlim and create another:

```
    await this.semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    counter++;

    Uri uri = new Uri($"{api}/{keyProperty}", UriKind.Relative);
    string rowVersion = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        HttpResponseMessage getResponse = await this.httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (getResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            using (HttpContent httpContent = getResponse.Content)
            {
                JObject currentObject = JObject.Parse(await httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
                rowVersion = currentObject.Value<string>("rowVersion");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
    {
        SocketException socketException = httpRequestException.InnerException as SocketException;
        if (socketException != null && socketException.ErrorCode == PutHandler.ConnectionRefused)
        {
            this.semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(counter * 90 / 100, counter * 90 / 100);
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    this.semaphoreSlim.Release();
}
```

If I do this, what will happen to the other tasks that are waiting on the Semaphore that I just de-referenced?  My guess is that nothing will happen until the object is garbage collected and disposed.

Answer (score 0):

A `SemaphoreSlim` (just like any other object in .NET) will exist as long as there are references to it.

However, there is a bug in your code: the `SemaphoreSlim` being released is `this.semaphoreSlim`, and if `this.semaphoreSlim` is changed between being acquired and being released, then the code will release a different semaphore than the one that was acquired. To avoid this problem, copy `this.semaphoreSlim` into a local variable at the beginning of your method, and acquire and release that local variable.

More broadly, there's a difficult in the attempted solution. If you start 1000 tasks, they will all reference the old semaphore and ignore the updated `this.sempahoreSlim`. So you'd need a separate solution. For example, you could define a disposable "token" which is permission to call the API. Then have an asynchronous collection of these tokens (e.g., a Channel). This gives you full control over how many tokens are released at once.